# Problem with reading from a file and put information into struct in C (different var in struct, return error, non-nested function with var modif type)

Tags: c, struct, io

I want to write a program, which will read from a text file and put information into struct. In struct I have the name of an element (which is char array), a symbol of an element (V - vector, S - scalar, M - array), dimension and value. Later I will write this struct into another file.
This is my file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    FILE *wz, *wc;  
    int dimension, dimensionX, dimensionY;

    if (argc != 3) {                                
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
    printf("I should run this way:\n");
    printf("%s source\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }
    
    if( (wz= fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if( (wc= fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
    exit(2);
    }
    
    struct Vector 
    { 
        char keyWord;
        char elementName[20];
        int dimension;
        double V[dimension];
    };
    typedef struct Vector wek;

    struct Scalar 
    { 
        char keyWord;
        char elementName[20];
        double wartosc;
    };
    typedef struct Scalar ska;

    struct Array
    {
        char keyWord;
        char elementName[20];
        int dimensionX;
        int dimensionY;
        double M[dimensionX][dimensionY];
    };
    typedef struct Array mac;

            
    
    struct Vector w1, w2;
    struct Scalar s1, s2;
    struct Array m1, m2;
    
    
    wek readVector(FILE *wz);
{
    wek w;
    fscanf(wz, "%30s", &w.keyWord);
    fscanf(wz, "%30s", &w.elementName[0]);
    for (int j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
            fscanf(wz, "%10lf", &w.V[j]);
    return w;
}
    ska readScalar(FILE *wz);
{
    ska s;
    fscanf(wz, "%30s", &s.keyWord);
    fscanf(wz, "%30s", &s.elementName[0]);
    fscanf(wz, "%10lf", &s.wartosc);
    return s;
}
    mac readArray(FILE *wz)
{
    mac m;
    fscanf(wz, "%30s", &m.keyWord);
    fscanf(wz, "%30s", &m.elementName[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < m.dimensionX; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < m.dimensionY; ++j)
            fscanf(wz, "%10lf", &m.M[i][j]);
    return m;
}
    s1 = readScalar(wz);
    s2 = readScalar(wz);
    w1 = readVector(wz);
    w2 = readVector(wz);
    m1 = readArray(wz);
    m2 = readArray(wz);
    fclose(wz);
    fclose(wc);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is my text file

```
S scalar1 3
S scalar2 5
V vector1 3
2 4 7
V vector2 3
3 6 1
M array_A 3 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
M array_B 3 3
9 8 7
6 5 4
3 2 1
```

I get errors

```
primal.c: In function ‘main’:
primal.c:60:9: error: non-nested function with variably modified type
     wek readVector(FILE *wz);
         ^~~~~~~~~~
primal.c:67:12: error: incompatible types when returning type ‘wek {aka struct Vector}’ but ‘int’ was expected
     return w;
            ^
primal.c:75:12: error: incompatible types when returning type ‘ska {aka struct Scalar}’ but ‘int’ was expected
     return s;
            ^
```

Comment: Your text file seems wrong. Shouldn't `array_A 3 3` be `M array_A 3 3` and `array_B 3 3` be `M array_B 3 3`?

Comment: Yes thank you, I forget, but still I have errors

Comment: @Mark `C` standard does not support nested function, anyway remove the semicolon at the end of the function declaration `ska readScalar(FILE *wz);` --> `ska readScalar(FILE *wz)`.

Comment: Thanks it works, it was such easy mistake. Thanks

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warning.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconverson -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding;  1) use meaningful variable names, not `m` and `v`, etc.  2) the code uses the word `dimension` a lot, but does not really indication a dimension of `what`.  3) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest using: `fprintf( stderr, "..\n" )` and/or `perror( "message" );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `if( (wc= fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
    exit(2);`  before calling `exit()`, need to close the file pointer: `wz`

Comment: regarding: `if (argc != 3) {                                
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
    printf("I should run this way:\n");
    printf("%s source\n",argv[0]);`  1) should use: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE" %s sourcefile\n", argv[0] );`   And the expected value in `argc` would be `2`, not `3`